# PHP else statement not showing

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I have a custom field in a WP post called "profession." If this profession is RN, then I want one piece of text displayed. If the profession is not RN, then I want another piece of text displayed.

I added the following code to execute this function:

```
        <?php if ( $profession = 'RN' ) {
        echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Current license in this state</li><li>Graduated from accredited Nursing school</li><li>BCLS required</li><li>BSN and ACLS preferred</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
    } ?>
```

The problem is, the first echo statement is displaying even when the post does not have RN in the profession field. If I purposely break the if variable, then it defaults to the second echo statement across the board. I can't get the post to respond dynamically to one vs the other.

Am I missing something in this code that is causing one or the other to display for all instead of based on the parameter I am trying to set?

Comment: `if ( $profession === 'RN' )` <- try

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare in your if not assign.

```
=  is used to assign values
== is used for comparison, checks if value is equal
=== is used for strict comparison, checks if value and type are equal.
```

So your php if statement should look like this

```
if ( $profession == 'RN' ){
    code
}else{
    code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read how to use condition before writing.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
 <?php if ( $profession == 'RN' ) {
        echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Current license in this state</li><li>Graduated from accredited Nursing school</li><li>BCLS required</li><li>BSN and ACLS preferred</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
    } ?>
```

Comment: That's the site I used originally to create the code. Using the modified equals effectively kills the first line. It works when I use "=" but fails when I use "=="

Comment: @KyleBoreing, if you give = means you are assign a variable

Comment: Here is https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp how to create  a variable

Comment: The problem is not the variable. I already have this as a custom field, and it is recognized when I use "=" but not when I use "==," as stated previously.

My problem is not getting the first line to display. My problem is hiding it when any other variable is in place. I have posts that do not include that particular variable but are still displaying the first echo statement anyway.

Comment: I've even tried mapping the custom field to integers (RN=1, CT Tech=2, etc.), and I have the same problem. The first if statement is all or nothing. It will not recognize any difference unless I break it, then it defaults to the second statement.

Comment: Hi @KyleBoreing, please paste your full code

Comment: I've also tried not using echo statements and closed if/then statements, and the same thing happens.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if ( $profession == 'RN' ) {
    echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Current license in this      state</li><li>Graduated from accredited Nursing school</li><li>BCLS required</li>   <li>BSN and ACLS preferred</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
} else {
    echo '<li>Minimum 2 years experience</li><li>Other requirements to be determined by our client facility</li>';
} ?>
```

Comment: check for the modification on line 1